# Loading a div while @PostConstruct processing

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2.2

The matter is i have a page that bring some code from the internet and the connection of the net is going up and down so the page is taking long time to be rendered sometimes, so i want to show a loading image on that page while the @PostConstruct calling the URLs

i have tried to put this script to do it in my template

```
<script>
 $ = jQuery;
$(window).load(function(){
  $('#loading').show();
});
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#loading').fadeOut(1000);
}); 
</script>
```

but its only works after the @PostConstruct finishes

**any one know how to do it while the @PostConstruct processing ?**

Comment: @BalusC i am using both prime and richfaces,and i dont know what i am looking for i am not that expert in jsf2 :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to run anything while the @PostConstruct is processing ,also `$(document).ready(function()` will only works after the DOM is loaded ie. after @PostConstruct is finished its job, so as a work around that, you need to delete some lines from your script code and changing it to

```
<script>
 $ = jQuery;
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#loading').fadeOut(1000);
}); 
</script>
```

and let what ever link you use to call the @postProcessing  to show the loading div by adding this script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.linkClass').click(function(){
         $("#loading").show(); 
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Both `$(document).ready()` and `$(window).load()` will be executed AFTER `@PostConstruct` is finished executing. You cannot use these events to "asynchronously" display a different div while your page content is still loading.

However, as a work around, you can let the loader div to be rendered while the browser is still in the process of forming the DOM by adding it as the first element inside the `<body>` tag, and prevent the browser to render the page content by wrapping it in a hidden div. The loader div will be hidden and the content div will be shown after the DOM is fully formed, that is after the `@PostConstruct` is finished executing

1. Create a div for holding the loading image and message. **Make sure
   that this div is the first element inside the `<body>` tag**.

   ```
   <div id="loading-wrapper">
      Loading...
   </div>
   ```
2. The **next element right after the loading-wrapper** should be the page content. Wrap it in
   a hidden div

   ```
   <div id="content-wrapper" style="visibility: hidden;">
      <!--Page content here-->
   </div>
   ```

   Make sure that `visibility: hidden` is defined inline.

After the DOM is fully formed, hide the loader div and show the content div

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#content-wrapper").css("visibility", "visible"); 
    $("#loading-wrapper").css("visibility", "hidden"); 
});
```

Comment: +1 but could'nt step 2 be eliminated by putting the loading-wrapper on top of everything else?

Comment: If step 2 is removed, then the actual page content will be rendered below the loading message which might show odd appearance since some binding might still be being evaluated in the backing bean (in the @PostConstruct).

Comment: sorry but this is gave me the same result